# Magento 2 Magnifier using set the zoom product image at mobile device

Tags: magento2, product-images

I want to magnifier enable at the product details page using this way. but there magnifier enable at the desktop device.

```
 <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
  </var>
```

Actually i want to enable magnifier at the mobile device.

Comment: did you get the solution ?